# Drupal message(on view node) is shown even after form submission

Tags: 7, rules, status-messages

I want to show a drupal message on all the nodes of blog type:

I have the following rule:

```
{ "rules_show_message_on_blogs" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show message on blogs",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "workflow_rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "node_view" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : {
          "node" : [ "node" ],
          "type" : { "value" : { "blog" : "blog" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "view-mode" ], "value" : "full" } }      
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "drupal_message" : {
          "message" : "This is a feature",
          "type" : "warning",
          "repeat" : 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I also have a search form on all the pages of the site. The problem is that the message is also shown after submitting the search form.

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Comment: Presumably there are blog posts in the search results that are being displayed in the 'full' view mode? If so then this would be the expected behaviour. Try changing your search results to use the teaser view mode instead of full, that should help

Comment: I tried changing the criteria. Even if I enter some query without any search results. Drupal message gets popped up

Comment: There must be something about your search workflow that invokes a full node view for a blog page; that rule simply won't fire unless `node_view()` is called on a node of type 'blog', with 'full' as the view mode argument. Without knowing more about your setup and what customisations you've made it's going to be very hard to suggest a solution

Comment: Can you please try this on a vanilla drupal installation. I am sure you will be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Have you tried it on a vanilla installation yourself? With no contrib modules installed and no configuration set up? If so this is a bug and I'd advise taking it to the Rules issue queue

Comment: yeah, I did. To my investigation, I think it is the search form action that helps this rule get executed unintentionally. The form action of search is normally equal to the current page url. When the search form gets submitted, it probably loads node again this rule is fired.